# For sequence $b_{n}=\frac{\ln(-2a_{n}-1)}{a_{n}+1}$ is there divergent sequence $a_{n}$, that sequence $b_{n}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

For sequence $b_{n}=\frac{\ln(-2a_{n}-1)}{a_{n}+1}$ is there divergent sequence $a_{n}$, that sequence $b_{n}$ is convergent?

I know that in general to be sequence $b_{n}$ convergent, sequence $a_{n}$ has to be convergent, so has limit $a$. Also $a_{n}$ and $a$ must not be $-1$. Because of the logatihm of course $a_{n} < -\frac{1}{2}$ and $a < -\frac{1}{2}$.

So any suggestions, how to get divergent sequence $a_{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

- First notice that $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln(-2x-1)}{x+1}$ is strictly decreasing.

To ease calculations let consider for $x>0\ :\ g(x)=\frac 12f(-\frac{x+1}2)=\dfrac{\ln(x)}{1-x}$

$$g'(x)=\dfrac{x\ln(x)-x+1}{x(1-x)^2}=\dfrac{h(x)}{x(1-x)^2}$$

Since $h'(x)=\ln(x)$ then the minimum of $h$ is reached at $x=1$ with $h(1)=0$.

Therefore $g'(x)\ge 0$ with equality potentially only in one point $x=1$ (in fact $g'(1)=\frac 12$ but it is not important).

We conclude that $g$ is strictly increasing on $(0,+\infty)$, making $f$ strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,-\frac 12)$.

> In particular $f$ is injective, this rules out $a_n$ being divergent by having multiple adherence values.

- This means that $a_n\to-\infty$

As a consequence $b_n\sim\dfrac{\ln(-2a_n)}{a_n}\to 0$

> So any sequence $a_n$ that goes to $-\infty$ is solution to the original problem.

Justification of $\phi(u)=\dfrac{\ln u}u\ $ behaviour in $+\infty$:

$\phi'(u)=\dfrac{1-\ln(u)}{u^2}<0\ $ for $\ u> 1\ $ so $\phi\searrow$ at infinity, and since $\phi(u)\ge 0$ on $\mathbb [1,+\infty)$

Therefore $\phi$ is bounded by a constant $M$ on $\mathbb [1,+\infty)$.

For $u> 1$ then $\sqrt{u}> 1$ and we have :

$$\phi(u)=\dfrac{\ln(u)}u=\dfrac{\ln({\sqrt{u}\hphantom{i}}^2)}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{u}}=\underbrace{2}_{cst}\times\underbrace{\dfrac{\ln(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u}}}_{\lvert\phi(\sqrt{u})\lvert \le M}\times\underbrace{\dfrac 1{\sqrt{u}}}_{\to 0}\to 0$$

Comment: This looks like a nice answer (though I think a bit hard for the OP to understand) but I am not sure your calculations are right... first of all $g(x) = \dfrac{2 \ln(x)}{1-x}$ then I do not understand how you derive your expression. Also, $\phi'(u) = \dfrac{1- \ln(u)}{u^2}$, and $\phi$ is only positive on $[1,\infty)$ so $\phi$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}^+$ but on $[1,+\infty)$ for example.

Comment: @Axel Pfieww, so full of small mistakes, thanks for pointing out (am I that tired ?), I have edited to hopefully a proper version. Yet I agree that it is a demanding answer for OP, but just reading the bullet points and highlighted parts without entering into calculation details makes it easy to grasp the main ideas.

Comment: I meant that, $h'<0$ on $(0,1)$ and $h'>0$ on $(1,+\infty)$ so $h$ is $\searrow$ then $\nearrow$ meaning there is a minimum in $x=1$. And since $1$ is a pole of $g'$ even if $h(1)=0$ we have to carry on a Taylor expansion and $g'(1)$ is effectively $\frac 12$, but that does not matter for the sign of $g'$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad. I must be tired too.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : Take for all $n\geq1$, $a_n = -n$

Comment: So limit for this sequence is $-\infty$, so limit for $b_{n}$ is then $\frac{\infty}{-\infty}$, how I understand that?

Comment: @NikiSedlarevič  $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\ln(2n-1)}{1-n} =0$